# Puppeteer: Get innerHTML

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, webautomation, puppeteer

Does anybody know how to get the `innerHTML` or text of an element? Or even better; how to click an element with a specific `innerHTML`? This is how it would work with normal JavaScript:

```
var found = false
$(selector).each(function() {
    if (found) return;
    else if ($(this).text().replace(/[^0-9]/g, '') === '5' {
        $(this).trigger('click');
        found = true
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 48, accepted):

This is how i get innerHTML:

```
page.$eval(selector, (element) => {
  return element.innerHTML
})
```

Comment: I do this and console log element.innerHTML and it prints out Promise { <pending> }. Even though elements have been rendered to browser(headless false). Do you have any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: Please try this as well                                                                                       `await page.goto('https://example.com');                                                  
const textContent = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('p').textContent);
const innerText = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('p').innerText);       
console.log(textContent); 
console.log(innerText);`

Answer (score 34):

### Returning innerHTML of an Element

You can use the following methods to return the [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) of an element:

#### [page.$eval()](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevalselector-pagefunction-args-1)

```
const inner_html = await page.$eval('#example', element => element.innerHTML);
```

#### [page.evaluate()](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args)

```
const inner_html = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('#example').innerHTML);
```

#### [page.$()](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageselector) / [elementHandle.getProperty()](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#elementhandlegetpropertypropertyname) / [jsHandle.jsonValue()](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#jshandlejsonvalue)

```
const element = await page.$('#example');
const element_property = await element.getProperty('innerHTML');
const inner_html = await element_property.jsonValue();
```

---

### Clicking an Element with Specific innerHTML

You can use the following methods to click on an element based on the [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) that is contained within the element:

#### [page.$$eval()](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevalselector-pagefunction-args)

```
await page.$$eval('.example', elements => {
  const element = elements.find(element => element.innerHTML === '<h1>Hello, world!</h1>');
  element.click();
});
```

#### [page.evaluate()](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args)

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
  const elements = [...document.querySelectorAll('.example')];
  const element = elements.find(element => element.innerHTML === '<h1>Hello, world!</h1>');
  element.click();
});
```

#### [page.evaluateHandle()](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatehandlepagefunction-args) / [elementHandle.click()](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#elementhandleclickoptions)

```
const element = await page.evaluateHandle(() => {
  const elements = [...document.querySelectorAll('.example')];
  const element = elements.find(element => element.innerHTML === '<h1>Hello, world!</h1>');
  return element;
});

await element.click();
```

Answer (score 12):

This should work with puppeteer:)

```
const page = await browser.newPage();
const title = await page.evaluate(el => el.innerHTML, await page.$('h1'));
```

Comment: You're evaluating twice here. It seems like a bad idea.

Comment: This could be useful if `await page.$('h1')` was called earlier and you planned on using the element handle multiple times.

Answer (score 6):

You can leverage the [`page.$$(selector)`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageselector) to get all your target elments and then use [`page.evaluate()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args) to get the content(`innerHTML`), then apply your criteria. It should look something like:

```
const targetEls = await page.$$('yourFancySelector');
for(let target of targetEls){
  const iHtml = await page.evaluate(el => el.innerHTML, target); 
  if (iHtml.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '') === '5') {
    await target.click();
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I can never get the .innerHtml to work reliable. I always do the following:

```
let els = page.$$('selector');
for (let el of els) {
  let content = await (await el.getProperty('textContent')).jsonValue();
}
```

Then you have your text in the 'content' variable.

Answer (score 3):

With regard to this part of your question...

> *"Or even better; how to click an element with a specific innerHTML."*

There are some [particulars](http://perfectionkills.com/the-poor-misunderstood-innerText/) around innerHTML, innerText, and textContent that might give you grief. Which you can work-around using a sufficiently loose XPath query with [Puppeteer v1.1.1](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.1.1/docs/api.md).

Something like this:

```
const el = await page.$x('//*[text()[contains(., "search-text-here")]]');
await el[0].click({     
                button: 'left',
                clickCount: 1,
                delay: 50
            });
```

Just keep in mind that you will get an array of ElementHandles back from that query. So... the particular item you are looking for might not be at [0] if your text isn't unique.

[Options](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#elementhandleclickoptions) passed to .click() aren't necessary if all you need is a single left-click.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write as below. (no need await sentence in the last part)

```
const center = await page.$eval('h2.font-34.uppercase > strong', e => e.innerHTML);
```

Answer (score -15):

```
<div id="innerHTML">Hello</div>


var myInnerHtml = document.getElementById("innerHTML").innerHTML;
console.log(myInnerHtml);
```

Comment: Unrelated answer

Comment: Must be use puppeteer