# how to select innerHTML from an elementHandle in puppeteer

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Using the node puppeteer module, how do I continue with this code to get the innerContent here?

```
const els = Promise.all(await page.$$(selector)).then(results => {
    results.map(async el => {
      const tr = await el.$('tr')
      //How do I convert this element handle to get its innerText content?
         })
     })
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Puppeteer: Get inner HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46431288/puppeteer-get-inner-html)

Answer (score 3):

Like this

```
textValue = tr.getProperty('innerText').jsonValue()
```

Comment: I cant edit it anymore, but the updated way is `textValue = await (await tr.getProperty('innerText')).jsonValue()`