# How to read the value of an span element with Puppeteer

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I am trying to do some web scraping reading some lines inside a html page. I need to look for a text which is repeated through the page inside some `<span>` elements. In the following example I would like to end with an array of strings with ['Text number 1','Text number 2','Text number 3']

```
<html>
    ...
    <span>Text number 1</span>
    ...  
    <span>Text number 2</span>
    ...
    <span>Text number 3</span>
    ...
</html>
```

I have the following code

```
sElements = ' ... span'; // I declare the selector.
cs = await page.$$(sElements); // I get an array of ElementHandle
```

The selector is working as in Google Chrome developer tools it captures exactly the 3 elements I am looking for. Also the cs variable is filled with an array of three elements. But then I am trying

```
for(c in cs)
    console.log(c.innerText);
```

But undefined is logged. I have tried with .text .value .innerText .innerHTML .textContent ... I do not know what I am missing as I think this is really simple

I have also tried this with the same undefined result.

```
cs = await page.$$eval(sElements, e => e.innerHTML);
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is an example that would get the innerText of the last span element.

```
  let spanElement;

  spanElement = await this.page.$$('span');
  spanElement = spanElement.pop();
  spanElement = await spanElement.getProperty('innerText');
  spanElement = await spanElement.jsonValue();
```

If you still are unable to get any text then ensure the selector is correct and that the span elements have an innerText defined (not outerText). You can run $(selector) in Chrome console to check.

Comment: this worked for me, but is there a cleaner way? That's a lot of code to just get innerHTML, thanks

Comment: You can evaluate in the context console to get properties. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/46565796/4068558