# How to get text inside <a href> tag without the link in href, with Puppeteer

Tags: html, testing, web-scraping, puppeteer

I am trying to scrape some date inside an  tag, but I do not want to get the link that is inside it.

Not really sure how to approach the problem since the  tags do not have ID's or classes

```
<div id="list-section">
    <ul>
        <li data-store-id="1234">
            <div class="item">
                <p>
                    <strong>
                    <a target="_blank" href="www.somelink.com"> NAME ONE </a>
                    </strong>
                </p>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li data-store-id="1234">
            <div class="item">
                <p>
                    <strong>
                    <a target="_blank" href="www.somelink.com"> NAME TWO </a>
                    </strong>
                </p>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I am trying to have every name in an array at the end [NAME ONE, NAME TWO] etc.

Edit: using node with puppeteer

Comment: I _do_ want to do this with puppeteer! Sorry if it was unclear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have the names in an array in two steps:

- Select the anchor tags `<a>...</a>`
- Get their inner HTMLs

As Douglas mentioned before, you can use XPath, but in this case simple CSS selectors will do the job just fine. As a CSS selector, many combination can get you the anchor tags: `#list-section a`, `ul a`...

Choose the one that fits you most and is least likely to brake later.
I recommend using the first one:

```js
const anchorTags = await page.$$("#list-section a")
```

As to getting the inner HTML of an element, this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46431288/puppeteer-get-inner-html) will definitely help you. My preferred approach is to have a separate asynchronous function defined as follows:

```js
async function getInnerHtml(page, target){
  const innerHTML = await page.evaluate(el => el.innerHTML, target)
  return innerHTML
}
```

This way you would loop on your array and call it on your anchor tags.

Don't forget that there is always many ways to build a scraper. Seems to me like you focused too much on the element, and wanted to select it *precisely*.
Also, it is necessary to get a good grasp of CSS selectors, especially [CSS combbinators](https://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_combinators.asp).

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to find elements that is very useful when web scraping named [xpath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath). Never worked with puppeteer, but I've been worked a lot with selenium recently and I used xpath a lot.

Just a quick view in the docs of puppeteer and I found something that could be useful for you.

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagexexpression

Due to I don't have the full html page, I was able to make a simple xPath to demonstrate its power.

```
//div[@class='item']//a
```

You can also test xpath opening Google Chrome DevTools in "[Elements](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/inspect-styles/?hl=en-us)" tab and pressing CTRL+F

It's a nice tool for having when web scraping.